# Entity Framework, returning a created ID from Oracle database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I've made an API using the latest Entity Framework that connects to an Oracle database.

I'm using POST methods in a Java client to create a new object in a database through the API.

When I create a new object in the database, a trigger creates a unique ID for the object.

I'm trying to find a way to get the API to return the unique ID created by the trigger. I've searched around but as of yet to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the ID field in the Entity Framework designer set the StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity.

Comment: This won't work in Oracle. The OP is asking about Oracle DB.

Comment: Yes, it does work. I was doing that on an Oracle project at the time I posted it.